# Not Sure About What $(this) points to here

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this, mouseover

Just a quick question about using $(this) in JQUery.

If you have something like:

```
$('li.biz').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).find('a.invisB').slideDown();
});
```

what will $(this) select? Does it select the single li.biz element that you mouse over and then slidedown the appropriate descendant elements or will it select ALL li elements with biz class when mouseover event occurs?

Comment: I just Googled ["jQuery this"](https://www.google.com.au/#q=jquery+this) and came across this article, which explains it extremely well: https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance:

```
$('li.biz').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).find('a.invisB').slideDown();
});
```

$(this) refers to li.biz, the 'li.biz' that is currently hovered.

It is set to find an anchor tag (link) inside it with the class 'invisB' and apply the function slideDown(); to it.

Here's a fiddle, with a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/d9rbrqqd/

Answer (score 1):

From the [`.mouseover(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) documentation:

> This method is a shortcut for .on( "mouseover", handler )

From the [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation:

> When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the
>   element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events
>   this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated
>   events this is an element matching `selector`.

In other words, `this` is simply the DOM element. In your scenario that would be the `li.biz` that triggered the event. Since `this` is just a DOM element, you need to wrap it (`$(this)`) in order to call jQuery functions on it.

Comment: Ok thanks. That's pretty much what I thought but thanks for explaining the way the handler works and which element is selected.